# How to create custom event in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, events, observer-pattern, symfony-components

I want to create custom events called `user_logged` so that i can attach my listeners to those events.

I want to execute few functions whenever user has logged in.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Create a class which extends `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event`.

Then, use the event dispatcher service to dispatch the event:

```
$eventDispatcher = $container->get('event_dispatcher');
$eventDispatcher->dispatch('custom.event.identifier', $event);
```

You can register your event listener service like so:

```
tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: custom.event.identifier, method: onCustomEvent }
```

Comment: Good answer.  In addition, there are more details here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html

Comment: Indeed, but this is a simple enough way to get started.

Comment: excellent answer!!, now the only question is where is the best place to dispatch a custom event?, maybe a service?

Comment: Events are usually dispatched in controllers, but can be also in dispatched in services if you need.

Comment: Using the `event_dispatcher` service worked for me! I used `$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher;` but that did not fire my event for some reason.

Answer (score 28):

This answer is little bit extend [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11661148/3612353).

services.yml

```
custom.event.home_page_event:
    class: AppBundle\EventSubscriber\HomePageEventSubscriber
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: custom.event.home_page_event, method: onCustomEvent }
```

AppBundle/EventSubscriber/HomePageEventSubscriber.php

```
namespace AppBundle\EventSubscriber;
class HomePageEventSubscriber
{
    public function onCustomEvent($event)
    {
        var_dump($event->getCode());
    }
}
```

AppBundle/Event/HomePageEvent.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Event;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
class HomePageEvent extends Event
{
    private $code;

    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }
}
```

anywhere you wish, for example in home page controller

```
    use AppBundle\Event\HomePageEvent;
    // ...
    $eventDispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
    $event = new HomePageEvent();
    $event->setCode(200);
    $eventDispatcher->dispatch('custom.event.home_page_event', $event);
```

Comment: Great! very helpful!

Comment: in my case giving error Service event_dispatcher not found why this error occur can you please help me asap thanks in advance