# In which file do i need to write code for attaching listener for EventDispatcher in symfony2

Tags: php, events, symfony, doctrine-orm

IN the [symfony2 Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html) , they say to use this code

```
$listener = new AcmeListener();
$dispatcher->addListener('foo.action', array($listener, 'onFooAction'));
```

I have two questions

1. IN which file do i need to write that line
2. what other events i can write in first arguments like `foo.action`. i mean is that event buitin or doctrine event or symfony event or custom defined

Comment: See this question that was just answered:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661057/how-to-create-custom-event-in-symfony2/11661148#comment15454258_11661148

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write in your controller like this

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();


            $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');
            $dispatcher->dispatch('your.event.name', new YourEvent($entity));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to if you're using the component as part of the framework. Just declare a service that's tagged as an event listener. As far as that event goes, it's an example of a custom-defined event. You can name your events whatever you'd like.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand that. i just want to know in which file i have to write the addListener line. or can give me code example what u mean.  also if the event is custom in which file to write the code of dispatching the event

Comment: @user1544681 You don't necessarily have to write the addListener line, you might just need to declare a service. Are you using the sf2 framework or the EventDispatcher component separately?

Comment: i am using sf2. can you give me sample code of yml file where what u are saying is accomplished

Comment: Just create a service like any other you have in your application, then put this under "tags": `- { name: kernel.event_listener, event: foo.action, method: onFooAction }`

Comment: ok that is cleared now but as given on their documentation do i need to write this thing anywhere  `$dispatcher->dispatch(StoreEvents::STORE_ORDER, $event);` i took it from their docs page

Comment: If you're using a custom event, then get the service from the container (`event_dispatcher`) and call the dispatch method on it where the first parameter is the event name and the second param is the actual event object.

Comment: But question is where to write that code, i mean in which file

Comment: i don't know. what i want is when that event happens like orderCreated , then i log that to text file. so where should i do that

Comment: Inside the event listener service that you've already created (i.e. the one you've tagged). You should probably read up on the observer pattern and on the symfony2 framework (actually read the documentation instead of just blindly copying code) as it will serve you best in the long run.

Comment: i read that from site but was confused. so you mean if i have the OrderListener service where i have the 'onFooAction' defined.there i need to write the disptach event code?? i tried reading docs many times but could not get it.

Comment: I think i need to write that code in my controller where my order iscreated and write that line after `flush()` is called. Am i right